# How to add timestamp to STDERR redirection

Tags: shell, scripting

In bash/ksh can we add timestamp to STDERR redirection?

E.g. myscript.sh 2> error.log

I want to get a timestamp written on the log too.

Answer (score 35):

If you're talking about an up-to-date timestamp on each line, that's something you'd probably want to do in your actual script (but see below for a nifty solution if you have no power to change it). If you just want a marker date on its own line before your script starts writing, I'd use:

```
( date 1>&2 ; myscript.sh ) 2>error.log
```

What you need is a trick to pipe stderr through another program that can add timestamps to each line. You *could* do this with a C program but there's a far more devious way using just `bash`.

First, create a script which will add the timestamp to each line (called `predate.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    echo "$(date): ${line}"
done
```

For example:

```
( echo a ; sleep 5 ; echo b ; sleep 2 ; echo c ) | ./predate.sh
```

produces:

```
Fri Oct  2 12:31:39 WAST 2009: a
Fri Oct  2 12:31:44 WAST 2009: b
Fri Oct  2 12:31:46 WAST 2009: c
```

Then you need *another* trick that can swap stdout and stderr, this little monstrosity here:

```
( myscript.sh 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3- )
```

Then it's simple to combine the two tricks by timestamping `stdout` and redirecting it to your file:

```
( myscript.sh 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3- ) | ./predate.sh >error.log
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> cat predate.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    while read line ; do
        echo "$(date): ${line}"
    done
pax> cat tstdate.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    echo a to stderr then wait five seconds 1>&2
    sleep 5
    echo b to stderr then wait two seconds 1>&2
    sleep 2
    echo c to stderr 1>&2
    echo d to stdout
pax> ( ( ./tstdate.sh ) 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3- ) | ./predate.sh >error.log
    d to stdout
pax> cat error.log
    Fri Oct  2 12:49:40 WAST 2009: a to stderr then wait five seconds
    Fri Oct  2 12:49:45 WAST 2009: b to stderr then wait two seconds
    Fri Oct  2 12:49:47 WAST 2009: c to stderr
```

As already mentioned, `predate.sh` will prefix each line with a timestamp and the `tstdate.sh` is simply a test program to write to `stdout` and `stderr` with specific time gaps.

When you run the command, you actually get `"d to stdout"` written to stderr (but that's your TTY device or whatever else `stdout` may have been when you started). The timestamped `stderr` lines are written to your desired file.

Comment: Why do you need to swap the output streams?

Comment: @Cameron: because the pipe `|` operates on standard _output,_ while the OP wanted manipulations done on standard _error._

Comment: But `( date 1>&2 ; myscript.sh ) 2>error.log` adds the date to `error.log` no matter the `myscript.sh` produce any error or not. Is there a way to add date only when `myscript.sh` produce an error?

Answer (score 30):

The `devscripts` package in Debian/Ubuntu contains a script called [`annotate-output`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/annotate-output.1.html) which does that (for both stdout and stderr).

```
$ annotate-output make
21:41:21 I: Started make
21:41:21 O: gcc -Wall program.c
21:43:18 E: program.c: Couldn't compile, and took me ages to find out
21:43:19 E: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
21:43:19 E: make: *** [all] Error 1
21:43:19 I: Finished with exitcode 2
```

Comment: A good tool for the job, but a drawback is that devscripts has a huge dependency list.

Comment: Use `apt-get install devscripts --no-install-recommends`

Comment: One potential problem with annotate-output is that it will not print out any unfinished (with \n) lines at the end.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a version that uses a `while read` loop like **pax's**, but doesn't require extra file descriptors or a separate script (although you could use one). It uses process substitution:

```
myscript.sh 2> >( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done > error.log )
```

Using **pax's** `predate.sh`:

```
myscript.sh 2> >( predate.sh > error.log )
```

Comment: I don't get anything in error.log for either of those cases (though I'm using Cygwin). Did this work for you?

Comment: I tried it in Cygwin just now and it doesn't work, but it works fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: So it does, just tried it in Ubuntu at home. It must be some sort of Cygwin problem. +1 for a simpler shorter, though much less devious, solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for your code. In addition: I use it for stdout and stderr: `myscript.sh &> >( predate.sh > error.log )`

Answer (score 17):

The program `ts` from the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package pipes standard input to standard output, and prefixes each line with a timestamp.

To prefix stdout lines: `command | ts`
To prefix both stdout and stderr: `command 2>&1 | ts`

Comment: Can you explain what is going on with the 2>&1 please?

Comment: @VictorEngel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean

Answer (score 4):

I like those portable shell scripts but a little disturbed that they fork/exec date(1) for every line. Here is a quick perl one-liner to do the same more efficiently:

```
perl -p -MPOSIX -e 'BEGIN {$!=1} $_ = strftime("%T ", localtime) . $_'
```

To use it, just feed this command input through its stdin:

```
(echo hi; sleep 1; echo lo) | perl -p -MPOSIX -e 'BEGIN {$|=1} $_ = strftime("%T ", localtime) . $_'
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing a script to pipe to, I prefer to write the logger as a function inside the script, and then send the entirety of the process into it with brackets, like so:

```
 # Vars    
 logfile=/path/to/scriptoutput.log

 # Defined functions
 teelogger(){
   log=$1
   while read line ; do
     print "$(date +"%x %T") :: $line" | tee -a $log
   done
 }


# Start process
{

echo 'well'
sleep 3
echo 'hi'
sleep 3
echo 'there'
sleep 3
echo 'sailor'

}  |  teelogger $logfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect back to stdout I found you have to do this:

```
myscript.sh >> >( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done )
```

Not sure why I need the `>` in front of the `(`, so `<(`, but thats what works.

Comment: Good stuff, short and gets the job done perfectly. Just to add that if you want to put that in a file instead of STDOUT, you need to insert the ">> filename" between 'done' and ')' like so: myscript.sh >> >( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done >> logfile )

Answer (score 2):

I was too lazy for all current solutions... So I figured out new one (works for `stdout` could be adjusted for `stderr` as well):

```
echo "output" | xargs -L1 -I{} bash -c "echo \$(date +'%x %T') '{}'" | tee error.log
```

would save to file and print something like that:
`11/3/16 16:07:52 output`

Details:

`-L1` means "for each new line"

`-I{}` means "replace {} by input"

`bash -c` is used to update `$(date)` each time for new call

`%x %T` formats timestamp to minimal form.

It should work like a charm if `stdout` and `stderr` doesn't have quotes (" or `). If it has (or could have) it's better to use:

```
echo "output" | awk '{cmd="(date +'%H:%M:%S')"; cmd | getline d; print d,$0; close(cmd)} | tee error.log'
```

(Took from my answer in another topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41138870/868947)

Answer (score 2):

How about timestamping the remaining output, redirecting all to stdout?

This answer combines some techniques from above, as well as from unix stackexchange [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/redirect-all-subsequent-commands-stderr-using-exec) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145651/using-exec-and-tee-to-redirect-logs-to-stdout-and-a-log-file-in-the-same-time). `bash` >= `4.2` is assumed, but other advanced shells may work. For < `4.2`, replace `printf` with a (slower) call to `date`.

```
: ${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT:="%F %T"} # override via environment
_loglines() { 
    while IFS= read -r _line ; do 
      printf "%(${TIMESTAMP_FORMAT})T#%s\n" '-1' "$_line";
    done;
}
exec 7<&2 6<&1
exec &> >( _loglines )
# Logit
```

To restore stdout/stderr:

```
exec 1>&6 2>&7
```

You can then use `tee` to send the timestamps to `stdout` *and* a logfile.

```
_tmpfile=$(mktemp)
exec &> >( _loglines | tee $_tmpfile )
```

Not a bad idea to have cleanup code if the process exited without error:

```
trap "_cleanup \$?" 0 SIGHUP SIGINT SIGABRT SIGBUS SIGQUIT SIGTRAP SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2 SIGTERM
_cleanup() { 
    exec >&6 2>&7
    [[ "$1" != 0 ]] && cat "$_logtemp"
    rm -f "$_logtemp"
    exit "${1:-0}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBUG=1

LOG=$HOME/script_${0##*/}_$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S-%N).log
ERROR=$HOME/error.log

exec 2> $ERROR
exec 1> >(tee -ai $LOG)

if [ $DEBUG = 0 ] ; then
    exec 4> >(xargs -i echo -e "[ debug ] {}")
else
    exec 4> /dev/null
fi

# test
echo " debug sth " >&4
echo " log sth normal "
type -f this_is_error
echo " errot sth ..." >&2
echo " finish ..." >&2>&4
# close descriptor 4
exec 4>&-
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing: nohup myscript.sh 2> >( while read line; do echo "$(date): ${line}"; done > mystd.err ) < /dev/null &

Works as such but when I log out and log back in to the server, it does not work. that is mystd.err stop getting populated with stderr stream even though my process (myscript.sh here) still runs.

Does someone know how to get back the lost stderr in the mystd.err file back?

Comment: It's not lost, just your new (pseudo) terminal of your new login session also has a new and different stderr. If you want to run programs persistently and re-attach them to new terminals, investigate using screen or tmux instead of nohup. Or redirect stderr to a file, and tail -f that file in new sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add my 2 cents worth..

```
#!/bin/sh

timestamp(){
  name=$(printf "$1%*s" `expr 15 - ${#1}`)
  awk "{ print strftime(\"%b %d %H:%M:%S\"), \"- $name -\", $$, \"- INFO -\", \$0; fflush() }";
}

echo "hi" | timestamp "process name" >> /tmp/proccess.log
```

printf "$1%*s" `expr 15 - ${#1}`
Spaces the name out so it looks nice, where 15 is the max space issued, increase if desired

outputs >> Date - Process name - Process ID - INFO - Message

```
Jun 27 13:57:20 - process name     - 18866 - INFO - hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirections are taken in order. Try this:

Given a script -

```
$: cat tst
echo a
sleep 2
echo 1 >&2
echo b
sleep 2
echo 2 >&2
echo c
sleep 2
echo 3 >&2
echo d
```

I get the following

```
$: ./tst 2>&1 1>stdout | sed 's/^/echo $(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S) /; e'
20180925T084008 1
20180925T084010 2
20180925T084012 3
```

And as much as I dislike awk, it does avoid the redundant subcalls to date.

```
$: ./tst 2>&1 1>stdout | awk "{ print strftime(\"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S \") \$0; fflush() }"; >stderr

$: cat stderr
20180925T084414 1
20180925T084416 2
20180925T084418 3

$: cat stdout
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the easiest way for me to accomplish this :

```
./script.sh 2> >(tee >(ts "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" >> script-stderr.log))
```