# Force a shell script to fflush

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering if it was possible to tell bash that all calls to `echo` or `printf` should be followed up by a subsequent call to `fflush()` on stdout/stderr respectively?

A quick and dirty solution would be to write my own printf implementation that did this and use it in lieu of either built in, but it occurred to me that I might not need to.

I'm writing several build scripts that run at once, for debugging needs I *really* need to see messages that they write in order.

Comment: Not that I know of, I think that BASH is completely line based so they will flush on a line by line basis but no more. Is there a need to not flush on newlines?

Comment: @Robert - Yes, I have to eliminate timing bugs as a culprit, thus I need to make sure every write to stderr / stdout causes the stream to be flushed.

Comment: Grasping at straws: I wonder if setting something using `stty` would help. Or using the `expect` script called `unbuffer`. Or setting Bash's `PS4` to include `$(date "+%s.%N")` (although there's a bit of overhead there) and using `set -x` and sorting the output. Perhaps something using `trap 'foo' DEBUG. Does [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/) provide any useful information? Or something [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection)?

Comment: @Dennis - I appreciate the stab. The problem is, I'm collecting the dump from several background processes in one place and need to be sure that I'm seeing ordering issues vs lags due to buffering.

Comment: @Dennis - Additionally, I did look to see if `stty` offered something that might help (or might expose something that would), no luck.

Comment: Did you work out a solution to this? I need to see a logfile as its generated by a background process.

Comment: @AsheeshR Yes, see the accepted answer.

Comment: For files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429951/force-flushing-of-output-to-a-file-while-bash-script-is-still-running

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If comands use stdio and are connected to a terminal they'll be flushed per line.
Otherwise you'll need to use something like stdbuf on commands in a pipe line
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

tl;dr: instead of `printf ...` try to put to the script `stdbuf -o0 printf ..`, or `stdbuf -oL printf ...`

Comment: I was thinking of just implementing stdbuf independently, I'm dealing with a portability issue with systems that have an older version of coreutils (or, more simply `xxprintf` that just flushes the given stream / fd)

Comment: It seems like the only way to do this is with stdbuff, implementing it yourself if it is not present.

Answer (score 3):

If you force the file to be read, it seems to cause the buffer to flush.  These work for me.

Either read the data into a useless variable:

```
    x=$(<$logfile)
```

Or do a UUOC:

```
    cat $logfile > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "stty raw" can help with some other tricks for end-of-lines handling. AFAIK "raw" mode turns off line based buffering, at least when used for serial port ("stty raw < /dev/ttyS0").