# How to derive current date and time and append at the end of each line that contains 'Hello'

Tags: date, awk, grep

I have the following file `party.txt` that contains something like the following:

```
Hello Jacky
Hello Peter
Bye Johnson
Hello Willy
Bye Johnny
Hello Mary
Hello Wendy
```

I used the `grep hello` to capture the contents, but when I use the `print date +"%Y-%m-%d'` and append to it, I cannot, and I will get many `0` per line.

```
cat party.txt | grep Hello | awk '{ print date +"%Y-%m-%d"}'
```

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %r")" '/Hello/ { print $0, date}' party.txt
```

Results:

```
Hello Jacky 2012-09-11 07:55:51 PM
Hello Peter 2012-09-11 07:55:51 PM
Hello Willy 2012-09-11 07:55:51 PM
Hello Mary 2012-09-11 07:55:51 PM
Hello Wendy 2012-09-11 07:55:51 PM
```

Note that the date value is only set when `awk` starts, so it will not change, even if the command takes a long time to run.

Comment: If combine with danfuzz's answer, it would be near to perfect.

Comment: The problem I have with this solution, is that the date is set once.  if you have a file (or stream) that takes several seconds or minutes to parse, every entry will have the exact same date/time stamp.  Also awk is not the universal command that supports -v, nawk is.  on Solaris, this won't work, but if you replace awk with nawk, it will work, you could also use gawk (the POSIX/GNU compliant version).  I prefer Alin's answer which works on all awk implementations and operating systems (provided awk is replaced by gawk)

Answer (score 42):

gawk (and recent versions of mawk) have a built-in [time/date function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), so there is no need to use external tools there.

```
gawk '/Hello/{print NR " - " $0 " - " strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}' party.txt
```

Comment: the only change I would make is to replace awk with gawk on operating systems where awk is not the POSIX/GNU compliant version.  Well, that and to remove the line number which wasn't part of the original request.

Answer (score 4):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{"date +'%Y-%m-%d'"|getline d;}/Hello/{print $0,d}' file
```

will give you:

```
Hello Jacky  2012-09-11
Hello Peter 2012-09-11
Hello Willy 2012-09-11
Hello Mary 2012-09-11
Hello Wendy 2012-09-11
```

Comment: If combine with danfuzz's answer, it would be near to perfect.

Answer (score 4):

This solution should work with any awk:

```
awk '/Hello/ {cmd="(date +'%H:%M:%S')"; cmd | getline d; print d,$0; close(cmd)}' party.txt
```

The magic happens in `close(cmd)` statement. It forces `awk` to execute `cmd` each time, so, date would be actual one each time.

`cmd | get line d` reads output from `cmd` and saves it to `d`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the direct question, what you're missing is that `date` is an external command, and so you need to either invoke it outside of awk and pass it in as a variable (as one of the other answers demonstrates), or invoke it from within awk as a system command either using the `system()` built-in or a pipe (as another one of the other answers demonstrates).

The reason you see `0` is because the expression `date +"%Y-%m-%d"` is being interpreted as adding the numeric value of the variable `date` (which will be `0` as it's not defined) to the numeric value of the string `"%Y-%m-%d"` (which will be `0` as it's not a valid number).

Comment: If combine with either steve or kent answer, it would be near to perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using Perl:

```
perl -MPOSIX -lne 'if (/Hello/){ print "$_ " . strftime "%Y-%m-%d",localtime }' party.txt
```

produces this output

```
Hello Jacky 2015-10-01
Hello Peter 2015-10-01
Hello Willy 2015-10-01
Hello Mary 2015-10-01
Hello Wendy 2015-10-01
```

Here's how it works:

- `-n` loops around every line of the input file, do not automatically print each line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-e` execute the perl code
- `$_` is the current line
- `-MPOSIX` loads the POSIX module, which includes `strftime`
- `localtime` and `strftime` prints the time, given the format `%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 0):

using posix sed (and a sub shell due to missing time function in sed)

```
sed -n "/^Hello/ s/$/ $( date +'%Y-%m-%d' )/p" party.txt
```

return

```
Hello Jacky 2016-11-10
Hello Peter 2016-11-10
Hello Willy 2016-11-10
Hello Mary 2016-11-10
Hello Wendy 2016-11-10
```

Answer (score 0):

In gawk only:

```
$ gawk '/Hello/ {print $0, strftime("%Y-%m-%d");}' party.txt 
Hello Jacky 2019-09-17 
Hello Peter 2019-09-17 
Hello Willy 2019-09-17 
Hello Mary 2019-09-17 
Hello Wendy 2019-09-17
```