# Redirect stdout to a file and add a timestamp

Tags: shell, scripting

I've found this script ([How to add timestamp to STDERR redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection?lq=1)) to redirect stdout/stderr of a script/program and add a time stamp:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line ; do
    echo "$(date): ${line}"
done
```

when using this script (predate.sh) like

```
./MyApp | predate.sh > out.log
```

it works great, but when MyApp crashes or gets killed, the predate.sh script continuously runs and does not terminate. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a buffering issue. I think this will work for you:

```
producer | stdbuf -oL gawk '{print strftime("%F %T"), $0}' > out.log
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I'm working on an embedded device and stdbuf is not available

Answer (score 0):

Add a timeout to your `read` and if it times out, check whether MyApp is running, quit if not, read again if it is.

```
read -t 1 line
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    # Timeout - check MyApp ruuning
    ps ... | grep MyApp ...
fi
```