# Adding a timestamp to stdout

Tags: shell, batch-file, scripting, stdout, logfile

i found these two similar questions: [Redirect stdout to a file and add a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792950/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-and-add-a-timestamp) and [How to add timestamp to STDERR redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection?lq=1) to redirect stdout to a file.

I want to add a timestamp when the line is written to the file. At the moment I wrtie the log file like this:

```
START cmd /c %PATH_STLink-OPENOCD%\openocd.exe -f %CD%\%CFG_File% -s %PATH_SUPPORTFILES% -d0 ^> output.txt
```

It would be nice, when the output could look like this (using %date% and %time%). Hopefully this is possible:

```
[10.03.2022, 16:11:40,45]output of openocd.exe
[10.03.2022, 16:11:42,21]output of openocd.exe
[10.03.2022, 16:11:43,65]output of openocd.exe
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<NUL >output.txt set /p=[%date%, %time%]
start ... >>output.txt
```

should put the prompt for the `set/p` into the new file `output.txt` with no newline; then append the data you want.

Comment: Thank you! :)
When I use your example, then it will set the date and time only in the first line. But I want that the timestamp should set to every output, which the OpenOCD.exe write to the stdout.