# how to add timestamp to the result of bash command for logging that can to file and screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell

this link can not solve my questtion perfectly [How to add timestamp to STDERR redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507674/how-to-add-timestamp-to-stderr-redirection)

First question: i don't want a output of command, which add timestamp with everyline, i just want to add  timestamp to first line, as the picture

Second question: atfer i execute the script , i must presss a enter key to end the process , how to solve 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmiNK.png)

> ```
>  #!/bin/bash 
>  exec > >(xargs -L1 -I{} bash -c "echo \$(date +'%x %T') '{}'" | tee error.log) 2>&1
>  errorcommand 
>  pwd 
>  ifconfig 
>  ls
> ```

```
 output:
    root@xintian-desktop:~# bash exec.sh
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 exec.sh: line 3: asdsad: command not found
    root@xintian-desktop:~# 2017年03月19日 10:31:51 /root
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 enxb827eb65188e Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:65:18:8e
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX packets:425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 TX packets:425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX bytes:34225 (34.2 KB)  TX bytes:34225 (34.2 KB)
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:30:4d:db
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 inet addr:192.168.88.26  Bcast:192.168.88.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 inet6 addr: fe80::11f7:7058:ec37:3064/64 Scope:Link
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX packets:342872 errors:0 dropped:203 overruns:0 frame:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 TX packets:17631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 RX bytes:69917459 (69.9 MB)  TX bytes:2141207 (2.1 MB)
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 20150305
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 20150405
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 20150505
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 aaa
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 aaa.bak
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 asd
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 error.log
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 exec.sh
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 nohup.out
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 python_act
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 sec
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 stderr.log
    2017年03月19日 10:31:51 trap.sh
```

Comment: Try something like `export PS1="\u@\h[\[\$(date)\]]\$ "`

Comment: it is no useful

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, I routinely add a timestamp line to the output of my scripts, especially those that run periodically.  There are lots of ways to do it.  Here's what I typically do:

```
   DATE=`date`
   echo "------------------- $DATE -------------------"
```

The key is executing the `date` command and printing the output in any format you want.

The simplest is to simply execute `date` by itself, without storing the output in a variable and then adding extra characters (in the snipped above I add extra "-" characters to make the timestamp line stand out in a log).  E.g.,

```
    date
```

You could also store the output in a variable using the more modern form:

```
    DATE=$(date)
```

You can of course format the timestamp line as you wish, e.g.,

```
    echo "== $0 running $DATE =="
```

Comment: it is so ugly, please share your all way